# React callback return not iterable instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using ant-desing(v3.26.14) List component in React. Normally if I try to pass plain array to 'dataSource' property then everything is fine. But when I try to pass array via callback it's given error.

```
<List dataSource={someArray} /> //is fine
<List dataSource={() => someArray} /> //getting error
```

Error: 'TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.'

I wonder is this normal behaviour of javascript or some library issue and why that's happening, isn't this the same thing?

Comment: Completely normal. List dataSource property expects an array, not a function

Comment: _"isn't this the same thing?"_ - No. In the first code example, you are passing an array; in the second one, you are passing a function. That's the difference. Your component library is expecting `dataSource` to be an array or an iterable and it breaks when you pass it a function instead of an array.

Comment: I understand, actually that make sense. So is there any way to manipulate this?

Comment: What do you mean by _"manipulate this"_? Just pass an array like in the first code example. However, you could pass an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) BUT that is completely unnecessary.

Comment: alright , thanks @Yousaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the `List` component is expecting the array so it can use the spread, but you are giving it a callback function. It doesn't expect a callback function but an iterator ( array in this case ).